# How Do I Access the Data in a tf.NamedTensorMap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm learning Tensorflow.js and I've ran into a problem. So, the data I'm using are ragged string vectors. I've tokenized the data using `tf.string.stringSplit()`, but I'm having trouble accessing the data now. I can call `split.values.print()` to get a console log of a summary of values in the tensor, but I can't figure out how to access the values directly. There's no documentation I could find about `tf.NamedTensorMap`s. I'd like to get the split values in the tensor as an array.

```
const sentence = tf.string.stringSplit(['Hello , World !'], ' ')

console.log(sentence.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I've looked seemingly everywhere for some documentation to explain `tf.NamedTensorMap`, but it doesn't seem to exist. After playing around with methods from the `Object` class, I realized I could access all of the method names by using `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. Also, by using `Object.keys()`, I was able to console log all of the property keys in `tf.NamedTensorMap`. So here is what I found.

It seems that each of `tf.NamedTensorMap.indices`, `tf.NamedTensorMap.values`, and `tf.NamedTensorMap.shape` have the same methods for some reason even though they hold different data. I'm assuming it's due to some inheritance. Anyway, I was able to locate multiple methods which can be used to get the data from the tensor. Namely `tf.dataSync()` and `tf.arraySync()` which both work for my specific scenario.

```
Tensor {
  rank: [Getter],
  buffer: [Function (anonymous)],
  bufferSync: [Function (anonymous)],
  array: [Function (anonymous)],
  arraySync: [Function (anonymous)],
  data: [Function (anonymous)],
  dataToGPU: [Function (anonymous)],
  dataSync: [Function (anonymous)],
  bytes: [Function (anonymous)],
  dispose: [Function (anonymous)],
  isDisposed: [Getter],
  throwIfDisposed: [Function (anonymous)],
  print: [Function (anonymous)],
  clone: [Function (anonymous)],
  toString: [Function (anonymous)],
  cast: [Function (anonymous)],
  variable: [Function (anonymous)],
  abs: [Function (anonymous)],
  acos: [Function (anonymous)],
  acosh: [Function (anonymous)],
  add: [Function (anonymous)],
  all: [Function (anonymous)],
  any: [Function (anonymous)],
  argMax: [Function (anonymous)],
  argMin: [Function (anonymous)],
  asScalar: [Function (anonymous)],
  asType: [Function (anonymous)],
  as1D: [Function (anonymous)],
  as2D: [Function (anonymous)],
  as3D: [Function (anonymous)],
  as4D: [Function (anonymous)],
  as5D: [Function (anonymous)],
  asin: [Function (anonymous)],
  asinh: [Function (anonymous)],
  atan: [Function (anonymous)],
  atan2: [Function (anonymous)],
  atanh: [Function (anonymous)],
  avgPool: [Function (anonymous)],
  batchToSpaceND: [Function (anonymous)],
  batchNorm: [Function (anonymous)],
  broadcastTo: [Function (anonymous)],
  ceil: [Function (anonymous)],
  clipByValue: [Function (anonymous)],
  concat: [Function (anonymous)],
  conv1d: [Function (anonymous)],
  conv2dTranspose: [Function (anonymous)],
  conv2d: [Function (anonymous)],
  cos: [Function (anonymous)],
  cosh: [Function (anonymous)],
  cumprod: [Function (anonymous)],
  cumsum: [Function (anonymous)],
  depthToSpace: [Function (anonymous)],
  depthwiseConv2d: [Function (anonymous)],
  dilation2d: [Function (anonymous)],
  divNoNan: [Function (anonymous)],
  div: [Function (anonymous)],
  dot: [Function (anonymous)],
  elu: [Function (anonymous)],
  equal: [Function (anonymous)],
  erf: [Function (anonymous)],
  exp: [Function (anonymous)],
  expandDims: [Function (anonymous)],
  expm1: [Function (anonymous)],
  fft: [Function (anonymous)],
  flatten: [Function (anonymous)],
  floor: [Function (anonymous)],
  floorDiv: [Function (anonymous)],
  gather: [Function (anonymous)],
  greaterEqual: [Function (anonymous)],
  greater: [Function (anonymous)],
  ifft: [Function (anonymous)],
  irfft: [Function (anonymous)],
  isFinite: [Function (anonymous)],
  isInf: [Function (anonymous)],
  isNaN: [Function (anonymous)],
  leakyRelu: [Function (anonymous)],
  lessEqual: [Function (anonymous)],
  less: [Function (anonymous)],
  localResponseNormalization: [Function (anonymous)],
  logSigmoid: [Function (anonymous)],
  logSoftmax: [Function (anonymous)],
  logSumExp: [Function (anonymous)],
  log: [Function (anonymous)],
  log1p: [Function (anonymous)],
  logicalAnd: [Function (anonymous)],
  logicalNot: [Function (anonymous)],
  logicalOr: [Function (anonymous)],
  logicalXor: [Function (anonymous)],
  matMul: [Function (anonymous)],
  maxPool: [Function (anonymous)],
  max: [Function (anonymous)],
  maximum: [Function (anonymous)],
  mean: [Function (anonymous)],
  min: [Function (anonymous)],
  minimum: [Function (anonymous)],
  mirrorPad: [Function (anonymous)],
  mod: [Function (anonymous)],
  mul: [Function (anonymous)],
  neg: [Function (anonymous)],
  norm: [Function (anonymous)],
  notEqual: [Function (anonymous)],
  oneHot: [Function (anonymous)],
  onesLike: [Function (anonymous)],
  pad: [Function (anonymous)],
  pool: [Function (anonymous)],
  pow: [Function (anonymous)],
  prelu: [Function (anonymous)],
  prod: [Function (anonymous)],
  reciprocal: [Function (anonymous)],
  relu: [Function (anonymous)],
  relu6: [Function (anonymous)],
  reshapeAs: [Function (anonymous)],
  reshape: [Function (anonymous)],
  resizeBilinear: [Function (anonymous)],
  resizeNearestNeighbor: [Function (anonymous)],
  reverse: [Function (anonymous)],
  rfft: [Function (anonymous)],
  round: [Function (anonymous)],
  rsqrt: [Function (anonymous)],
  selu: [Function (anonymous)],
  separableConv2d: [Function (anonymous)],
  sigmoid: [Function (anonymous)],
  sign: [Function (anonymous)],
  sin: [Function (anonymous)],
  sinh: [Function (anonymous)],
  slice: [Function (anonymous)],
  softmax: [Function (anonymous)],
  softplus: [Function (anonymous)],
  spaceToBatchND: [Function (anonymous)],
  split: [Function (anonymous)],
  sqrt: [Function (anonymous)],
  square: [Function (anonymous)],
  squaredDifference: [Function (anonymous)],
  squeeze: [Function (anonymous)],
  stack: [Function (anonymous)],
  step: [Function (anonymous)],
  stridedSlice: [Function (anonymous)],
  sub: [Function (anonymous)],
  sum: [Function (anonymous)],
  tan: [Function (anonymous)],
  tanh: [Function (anonymous)],
  tile: [Function (anonymous)],
  toBool: [Function (anonymous)],
  toFloat: [Function (anonymous)],
  toInt: [Function (anonymous)],
  topk: [Function (anonymous)],
  transpose: [Function (anonymous)],
  unique: [Function (anonymous)],
  unsortedSegmentSum: [Function (anonymous)],
  unstack: [Function (anonymous)],
  where: [Function (anonymous)],
  zerosLike: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Because of how tensors work, if I understand them now, attempting to make a tensor that contains tensors is a bad idea and it may not even work (I'd have to test that one out). So, if your data is anything like the data I'm using and you need to split your data at a lower level in your dataset, it's likely much better to use the basic `string.split()`.